# Is there any advantage of using angular js with magento?

Tags: angularjs, magento

Angular js is new in market so is there any advantage of using **angular js** with **magento**  ?

If yes then anyone knows how can we use both in a single project ?

Comment: Would use angular same way you do anywhere else. It doesn't care what server side language or framework is used

Comment: Thanks but advantage ?

Comment: Nobody can compare without a use case provided

Comment: I would propose using moltin.com, works quite well with Angular JS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Angular is not new in the market, it´s pretty old already. Anyway, the benefit of using Angular (or another client framework) is that your shop can be a lot faster - instead of a page refresh for every click, you can load data/templates with Angular. For example, with a REST API. Meaning: you only load what you need and the server can handle more users.

There are many resources about this topic already, here´s a small list:

- https://github.com/Wildhoney/Magento-on-Angular
- http://www.webspeaks.in/2014/03/integrating-angular-js-with-magento.html
- https://firebearstudio.com/blog/moa-magento-on-angular.html
- http://www.neevtech.com/blog/2013/04/12/lightning-fast-magento-store-with-json-angularjs-and-magento-j-a-m/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/Magento/comments/33mcgq/we_did_it_we_converted_our_magento_site_to_a/

Read through all those links and you will know why it´s good and how it can be done.